# Android : Java Blank Activity

Tags: java, android

I have created Blank activity and then I have made it full screen with those lines:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but how can I remove menu? When I press menu button the program gets crashed.
This is the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vahe_muradyan.fingercutter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/gameicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fingercutter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fingercutter.Game"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fingercutter.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.vahe_muradyan.fingercutter.About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried to change each Activity's theme but again it crashed.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your Activity class please? Thanks

Comment: please share your complete Activity code

Comment: I cant post it .The code is long sorry.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: can I make the program full screen from manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` attribute for `application` or `activity` (the one you want to be full screen) tag of the manifest.

Comment: if I use that can I remove this code?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it.

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: I have added the manifest can you edit it and post here?

Comment: Ok, I'll repeat. Replace `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". That's it. After that you can remove the code you posted... It's hard to guess what your problem actually is without seeing the logcat, please post it. Also, have you tried my answer's suggestion regarding menus?

Comment: yes I have tried it.how can I copy the logcat?

Comment: @user3624785 In Eclipse: Window -> Show View -> Others -> Android -> Logcat. Then run the app, you will see lots of errors in red. Post those errors here.

Comment: Onik can you give me your Skype?

Comment: Onik I found the reason.public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity,I changed it to public class MainActivity extends Activity. thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing mistake at onCreateOptionMenu.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Please check here or completely remove this